# OpenGl make objects "jump" every N seconds

Tags: c++, opengl

I am trying to make cubes that I am drawing appear to "jump" every few seconds. Here is my code:

```
            for (int i=0; i<25; i++)
            {
                if(j<rows)
                {

                    //Timer used in vibration calculation when drawing cubes
                    float time = (std::clock() - timer);
                    //Calculate the amount of simulated vibration based on amount of distortion (intensity)
                    float offset = sin(1.0f * 3.14159265359f * time) * shake;

                    //Draw cubes right and left of centre point
                    drawCube((x+xShift), y, (-300 +depth), 1.0f, cubeColour, offset);
                    drawCube((x-xShift), y, (-300 +depth), 1.0f, cubeColour, offset);
                    xShift -= gap;
                }
            }
```

And the drawCube code is:

```
void drawCube(float x, float y, float z, float opacity, float col[], float offset)
{
    //Draw cube taking into account any offset caused by simulated vibration
    glTranslatef((-x+offset), (-y+offset), -z);
    glColor4f(col[0], col[1], col[2], opacity);
    glutWireCube(20);
    glTranslatef((x-offset), (y-offset), z);

}
```

I'm assuming that I need to use a timer that raises the y value every N seconds so the cube appears to jump but am unsure how to do this?

Comment: I'm not sure how to make it "jump" either. What do you mean by "jump?" What *exactly* do you want to see?

Comment: Basically every N seconds I want the row of cubes to rise and fall in a quick sequence, so it looks like they bounce. So i guess I want them to rise 10.0f or so on the y-axis then fall back down to their original position. I want this action to be triggered every N seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is to adjust the y-coordinate in the call to `drawCube`. This should be the base value + the jump height.

One easy way to calculate the jump height at a time `t` is the following: Set up a variable that increases with time (preferrably an increase by 1 after 1 second). You should reset this variable after N seconds. So the variable runs from 0 to `N`.

This variable will be the base for the jump height calculation. If you define `jumpDuration` as the duration of the jump and `jump_height` as the maximum jump height, the jump offset can be calculated with two functions:

```
jump_offset = 0 // if t > jump_duration
jump_offset = -4 * jump_height / jump_duration^2 * t^2 + 4 * jump_height / jump_duration * t // else
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I understand what you mean. Just how would I go about increasing the variable every 1 second. I'm a bit unfamiliar with timers in c++.

Comment: You already used `std::clock()`. This function returns the processor time. You can convert it to seconds by dividing by `CLOCKS_PER_SEC`. If you save the current processor time in a variable, you get the elapsed time with `current_time - last_time`. If both values are in seconds, you can just add the difference to `t` (and reset it if `t > N`)